# My USB wont mount

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount

When i plug my USB into my computer it starts to flash but its undetectable from the computer. on windows it says unrecognized. it wont show up on Ubuntu. i have tried formatting it but i cant find it on there or anywhere else, i have also tried fixing it on windows. I have checked the devices and tried to update the drivers on the root hub. I have tried plugging it into 2 different USB ports on both computer.  It is a SanDisk 8GB USB.

help

Comment: Is it a brand new USB flash drive or has it been used before? If used before what for?

Comment: Are there any messages in `dmesg` relating to the usb in question? Also is you run `lsusb` from a terminal can you see the usb there? Is this a USB 3 device (had a blue connector) that you're trying to use in a USB 2 port (black connector)?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you 15 seconds of explanation then let's dive in. Physical disks will be noted with an alphabet letter and partitions will be noted as a number. A vanilla system will be sdax (x being a number) and the next drive (that USB) will become sdbx.

With the drive disconnected, open your shell and run the following command:

```
lsblk
```

You should see something like this:

```
sda                          8:0    0    35G  0 disk
├─sda1                       8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                       8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                       8:5    0  34.8G  0 part
  ├─mint--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0  33.2G  0 lvm  /
  └─mint--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   1.5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                         11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Now plug the drive in again and run the same command as above. Did you find the flash drive? If the answer is no, you probably have a bad drive. If the answer is yes, then let's mount it.

For explanation sake, I'm going to use sdb1. Replace this with sdbx, sdcx, etc..., whichever is correct on your system.

```
cd
mkdir usbflash
mount /dev/sdb1 usbflash
```

From this point you should now see the flash drive listed as usbflash in your file manager GUI, or you could just `cd usbflash` and work inside of the command line.

If you get that all fixed up, you can then see your drive with the following command:

```
mount
```

When you're done with your drive, you can unmount it by appending the path that you found from the command above:

```
umount /path-here
```

Comment: i did what you said and this is what i get `mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist` but when i plug another smaller usb in it works. im gonna try pulling it apart and seeing what it looks like

Comment: If you connect the flash drive and then type `lsblk` and you don't find that flash drive listed as sdbx, sdcx, etc... it's probably just a bad card. It doesn't need to be formatted correctly for Linux to at least detect that a device was connected. I've had several go bad over time. If and only if you actually do see the drive appear with `lsblk`, then consider trying to use g-parted to reformat the drive. You just have to be able to see it first.

Answer (score 0):

If the USB stick is not recognized by any computer, then it is probably bad (see other answers for various tests).  However, these sticks can go bad in one of two ways:
1) The memory goes bad (worn out,...)  or
2) The stick's reader electronics goes bad.

If you totally give up on the stick, try pulling it apart to see if the memory part is really a micro SD card.  Test the card in any standard card reader, it may still be good.